# Is there a need for file descriptor control program/syscall?

Tags: file, file-descriptor, system-calls, bsd

I am currently thinking of implementing a syscall in some BSD flavours in order to close a given file descriptor. 
The file descriptor would be defined as a pair of PID and file descriptor number.
It will be useful in order to test/debug a program or others strange purposes.

I think that I will do it anyway, you know, for learning purpose.
What I'm asking here is: can it be useful to someone somehow ? Can I publish my work and maintain it ?

I don't think any operating system will accept my code if there's no need for the end users or programmers.

Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

Come on, that would be useless, it's like taking back memory from a program while it's running. This will never happen in reality.

Code it just for the fun if you really want to, no one will ever need that.

Or maybe I'm missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

You could post it as a tutorial for kernel programming stuff. There aren't so much of them out there, and it's not as documented as one could expect.